# CSS3 scaled elements issue in Firefox

Tags: css

I've a simple `div` element having a select box in it. The `div` has been scaled down using css transform as:

```
<div>
    <select name="" id="">
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>

div {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.6);
       -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.6);
}
```

**In chrome:**

[image]

**In Firefox:**

[image]

Here is a demo (http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/sZSV3). There is the same issue with input boxes in iPad wherein cursor is misplaced when input gets a focus. Is there any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just met <kbd>[Bug 455164](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455164)</kbd>

> **CSS transforms** (that are more than just translations) **do not apply to the options of a selectbox**

This is not limited to `Scale`, but to almost any other CSS3 transformations.

Basically, you can style the `<select>`, but not its `<option>`s.

If you scale the select (by scaling its container), the options won't be resized, nor moved. In fact, the options will use as starting position their unscaled original position (try removing `Scale` transform and opening the select box to check this).

There is nothing you can do right now.

You need a B-plan: try finding another way to achieve what you need that doesn't use CSS3 transform (with Javascript for example), or that doesn't use the select box (by using custom selectboxes, for example... it's full out there).

Comment: Thanks @Andrea, The same problem is with input boxes in iOS where the cursor is misplaced.

Comment: Have you updated to 7.0.3 ? If it's this, it's fixed: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5390211

Comment: BTW this are two different questions... what about the provided one to the firefox bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that, option tag is not possible to style via CSS. But if you want, you can use jquery and style your [Select Box](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) easily.